# MemoryError due to the memory leak of struct.unpack() when reading multiple files of varying size

Tags: memory-leaks, struct, data-files

I am reading multiple data files of varying length using struct.unpack(). It works fine for files around 200MB, but gives MemoryError in struct.unpack() when the size of files exceed 200MB. A related discussion at http://bugs.python.org/issue14596 mentioned that the struct.unpack() works fine for same length of data files, and it produces memory leaks if the data files are of different length. I further tested multiple files of same size which accumulate upto 2GB, and it works fine.

So, what is the solution for reading multiple files of varying length using struct.unpack()?

Thank you
-Sabih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved now. Instead of using struct.unpack() to read multiple data files of varying length, numpy.fromfile() is found faster and there is no more issue of multiple files with varying data length. 
So, numpy.fromfile() is recommended to read multiple files with varying data length. I have tested for around 2GB (>250 files).
Sabih